# I want to change the font type and size in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting the error `<a class='gotoLine' href='#36:31'>36:31</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

<p>Click the button to display the value of the value attribute of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var x2 = x.style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x2;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;` change it to `var x = document.getElementById("myText");`.

Answer (score 0):

Update you JS function as,

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You had some errors in javascript. I have fixed it.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x.value;
   var y = document.getElementById("demo");
  y.style.fontFamily="Impact Charcoal sans-serif";
  y.style.border = "3px solid red";
  
}</script>
</head>
<body>

First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

<p>Click the button to display the value of the value attribute of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot. I have one doubt, is it possible to get the output in a box as well.

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Sure !

Comment: could you tell me how to put the output in a box, like what change can I make to the code

Comment: you can add css styling to the output

Answer (score 0):

> var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
> var x2 = x.style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";

In the above code, you are assigning value to `x` and then you are trying to change the `font family`. But x is of type `string`, string doesn't have any property called `style` so `x.style` will be `undefined`. This is why the error `Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined` while trying to access `fontFamily` on `undefined` value.

So instead of assigning `document.getElementById("myText").value` to `x`, assign `document.getElementById("myText")` to `x`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

  <p>Click the button to display the value of the value attribute of the text field.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myText");
      x.style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
      var x2 = document.getElementById("demo");
      x2.style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
      x2.innerHTML = x.value;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```